# Delphi - Changing TComboBox's OnChange

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I want to change the `TComboBox` so that if I type text into it or manually set the Text property it will trigger the `OnChange` event.

As it is now, doing `ComboBox.Text := 'blah'` doesn't trigger the `OnChange` event, nor does typing into the box.

I tried creating a `TComboBox` descendant, which I assume is the right approach, but I'm not really sure how to change what triggers the events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, typing into a combo box will result in the `OnChange` event firing. But it is true that modifying the text property does not.

The way I would go about getting `OnChange` to fire for your combo box is to handle the `CM_TEXTCHANGED` message. The handler for this needs to call the `Change` method which will then call `OnChange`, if it has been assigned.

As a simple example, here's an interposer class implementation:

```
type
  TComboBox = class(StdCtrls.TComboBox)
  protected
    procedure CMTextChanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_TEXTCHANGED;
  end;

procedure TComboBox.CMTextChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  Change;
end;
```

Comment: +1 for using a interposed class, IMHO this is the best approach.

Comment: I'm not sure what an interposed class is, but I did this in my descendant class and it worked. Thanks!