# How to enable onDraw (ownerDraw) for TDBLookupListBox

Tags: delphi

The TDBLookupListBox (I am using Delphi Xe5) does not have an onDraw event. I need to change text colour (or text's background colour) of items displayed in the list based on certain field's values. For example, if displaying a list of employees to pick from, show employees meeting a certain condition in grey or red color, etc.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: I am not normally a fan of DB controls as you have less control over things. That aside, in this case I would probably use a normal listbox and just put a bit of code in place to load and save from the DB when needed.

Comment: Either switch to another component or override the Paint method and implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ideal use case for interposing the control.

See: [Delphi - Changing TComboBox's OnChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665686/delphi-changing-tcomboboxs-onchange)

Something like this should do the trick (pseudo code, will refine later).

```
type
  TDBLookupListbox = class(DBcntls.TDBLookupListbox)
  private
    FOnDraw: TDrawEvent;
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    property OnDraw: TDrawEvent read FOnDraw write FOnDraw;
  end;

procedure TDbLookupListbox.Paint;
begin
  inherited;
  if Assigned(OnDraw) then FOnDraw(Self, Canvas);
end;
```